# MongoDB Aggregate query: see if value is in an array.

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array of ObjectIds, someOtherArray and need to compare them against the current objectId in the aggregate query.  I believe I most of the query done, but I'm not sure how to see if my current objectId is in the array, someOtherArray.  I comment on the code below on where I am stuck.

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
{
    $project: { 
        aField : {
            $map : {
                input: "$anArray",
                as : "arrayValue",
                //this is where I'm not sure on what to do.  I need something to return 
                //true or false on whether that item is in someOtherArray
                in: { $cond : {if: { $isInArray: [ $$arrayValue, someOtherArray] }, then: arrayValue, else: '' }}
            }
        } 
    }
}
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your overall purpose here is, but basically if you just want to test if the contents of one array matches the content of another supplied array ( or even another array field in the document ) then you can just test this with the [**`$setIntersection`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "present": { "$gt": [
            { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$anArray", someOtherArray ] } },
            0
        ]}
    }}
])
```

What is returned from `$setIntersection` is just the elements that are the "same" and as a "set" so removing duplicates. Maybe that is even what you want by it's own, without doing a [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) test on the result to see if anything was there.

If you are after some kind of "match mask" where the elements are returned from the original in their original positions where they matched something in the comparison array, then you can do something comparing both arrays against each other with a [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operation on each:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "altered": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$anArray",
                "as": "orig",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$anyElementTrue": {
                           "$map": {
                               "input": anotherArray
                               "as": "compare",
                               "in": { "$eq": [ "$$orig", "$$compare" ] }
                           }
                        }},
                        "$$orig",
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

And that would return an array of the same length as the original in the document but with only the "matched" elements in their original positions and all other elements represented as `false`. So the "truth" test here is by each element of the array to compare, then distilled to a single result using [**`$anyElementTrue`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/).

Keep in mind that these operations all act on a concept of "truth" or are otherwise a means of determining the "combination" of results in some way. So unless you are expecting `false` results in your output, then you probably want to filter first to remove those documents that will never contain a match. This is just an [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator for the query:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "anArray": { "$in": someOtherArray }
    }}
])
```

All assumptions here are that `someOtherArray` is an externally declared variable which is just going to "interpolate" with the BSON representation here, which it will. For using another field in the document you can just notate as `"$someOtherArray"` in all cases, with of course the exception of the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline which cannot compare fields, and would need you to [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the "truthiness" of that evaluation before you could "filter" on that result.

Comment: Is there anyway to boost performance on $setIntersection?  This query takes an awefully long time.  Before this I was running a match then unwind and match again and it seemed faster, but return some wrong results. ie) db.Collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "anArray": { "$in": someOtherArray }
    }}, {$unwind: "anArray"}, { "$match": {
        "anArray": { "$in": someOtherArray }
    }},
])

Comment: @raging_subs The best way is to limit the results in the pipeline, which is why I mention filtering first. You are not exposing everything you are doing here or what your final purpose is. So this makes it very difficult to comment. So match first, project, then match again to filter the results

Comment: After I get all of my matched points, is it possible to go up an level to get a field of an object that matched my id within the setIntersection? ie)
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "present": { 
            { "$setIntersection": [ "$anArray", someOtherArray ] } }.
"someField":"$UpAnObject.field" 
    }}
])

note when I say upAnObject I mean  {upAnObject :{ field: value, $anArrayComparison : { fieldToMatchSomeOtherArray: value }}}